# Conda install suddenly stop installing despite good network

Tags: linux, python, anaconda

I use miniconda version 4.12.0. When I install with pip, everything works perfectly fine. But whenever I install some large packages like `cudnn`, it couldn't finish downloading. I don't think it is the network issue as the downloading process stopped so sudden in the middle of the installation process. Can someone help me about this? Thank you in advance!!

Example log below:

```bash
$ conda install cudnn=8.2.1
.
.
.
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  cudatoolkit        pkgs/main/linux-64::cudatoolkit-11.3.1-h2bc3f7f_2
  cudnn              pkgs/main/linux-64::cudnn-8.2.1-cuda11.3_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? 


Downloading and Extracting Packages
cudnn-8.2.1          | 865.2 MB  | ##############################################3                                                                                                                   |  29% 
cudatoolkit-11.3.1   | 549.3 MB  | ####################################################################################4                                                                             |  52% 

CondaError: Downloaded bytes did not match Content-Length
  url: https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/cudnn-8.2.1-cuda11.3_0.conda
  target_path: /home/thanhtvt/miniconda3/pkgs/cudnn-8.2.1-cuda11.3_0.conda
  Content-Length: 907179703
  downloaded bytes: 260946309

CondaError: Downloaded bytes did not match Content-Length
  url: https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/cudatoolkit-11.3.1-h2bc3f7f_2.conda
  target_path: /home/thanhtvt/miniconda3/pkgs/cudatoolkit-11.3.1-h2bc3f7f_2.conda
  Content-Length: 575957943
  downloaded bytes: 302037379
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is something wrong with miniconda itself, when I install from `anaconda` channel, it works like a charm

```bash
conda install -c anaconda cudnn=8.2.1
```